# Facebook API Webhook - Get Post ID

Tags: php, facebook, api, webhooks

Can I get a specific post ID from a Webhook, currently I can make an API call and get all the data I need and store it locally to display to the user, however if I decide to use Webhbook to get new updates all they give me is a UID and ID which are both the same.

Is there any way to retrieve the specific post/notification ID through Webhook? Or does it only really tell you that you its time to make another API call and update/compare your records?

Here is an example of what I am returned -

```
{
 "object": "user",
 "entry": [
   {
      "uid": "123456789",
      "id": "123456789",
      "time": 1374846331,
      "changed_fields": [
       "feed"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: it depends on what you are subscribed to, if it is relevant to a post, you will receive the ID of the object.